# IE8 IE7 jquery cycle black background

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, cycle

I've seen my fair share of IE stuff, but never seen this before & no idea how to fix it. I've worked with jquery cycle plugin many times before without this problem.

Please see: http://vdpwebsites.com.au/tony/2012/rvu/index.html

Basically on IE8/7, the blue box that is scrolling to the left on the side section right of the website is black. If you view it in another browser you can see that it is blue & it's part of a background image. You can see the white below it, but it seems there is black covering the top part.

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each slide is getting black backguond applied in IE <= 8

I *think* it's because you need to set `cleartypeNoBg: true` in the cycle options

Comment: oops, should really have done a little more research. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - there is quite a lot of info for the cycle plugin so easy to miss :)